# How to forward socket connection through servlet?

Tags: java, networking, jakarta-ee, servlets, port

I am looking into trying to do UDP/TCP hole punching using a servlet running on Google's AppEngine.

I would be using primarily the Java EE library. But I don't quite see how to forward a network connection request from the client to the other client who is acting as the P2P "host".

Is there something I'm missing in the ServletRequest/ServletResponse classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you're going to be able to handle UDP.  However, for TCP, if you override the [service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method in the servlet and handle the "CONNECT" verb, you can then read from and write to the input and output streams.  From the client side, you should be able to utilize this through a HttpURLConnection or something like Apache HTTP Client.

Comment: What protocol does the standard Socket use when it is instantiated with an address to connect to?

Comment: @EJP Which method is the service method?  And what do you mean by "handling" the CONNECT verb?  Isn't that just a variable?

Comment: I was able to override the service method... but it still gets the request and response objects in its parameters.  Where does this CONNECT verb come from?

Comment: Oh and I should probably ask this now just to clarify... will this allow me to simply establish the connection between the two clients and then have the server back away?  Or does everything have to through the server?